# Importing Popper into App.vue breaks bootstrap functionality

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-5, popover

I am importing popover into my App.vue component `import { Popover } from 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.esm.min.js'` to enable popovers and the popovers work however other Bootstrap components have stopped working correctly. For example the dropdowns no longer open and the offcanvas's seem to have a double backdrop, so you have to press twice to close them. Not sure what is causing this strange behaviour - have I imported things in the wrong order? Anyone else experienced the same thing?

```
"@popperjs/core": "^2.11.2",
"bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
"popper.js": "^1.16.1",
"vue": "^3.0.0",
```

**EDIT**:
Live example here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-waterfall-c9g2ml?file=/src/App.vue

In the example above you'll see the popover is working but the offcanvas and collapse are not.
As soon as you comment out `window.bootstrap = require("bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js");` (line 83) the collapse and offcanvas work, but the popover does not and you get the following ref error: "*bootstrap is not defined*".

I haven't seen any documentation online that mention incompatibility.

Comment: There is probably no order to do things here. Did you checked that all of them are working with each other (compatible with Vue3 etc)? And read the docs accordingly? Some [repro] would be welcome here too, to help you debug the issue quicker.

Comment: @kissu I have edited my post above to answer your questions. Cheers

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: @V.Sambor still haven't solved it - have you had any luck? An additional note: I've noticed it's not specific to Popper - if you import 'bootstrap' into the App.vue this also breaks it.

Comment: At the end, following the official steps in how to import it is probably the best approach overall.

Comment: Which official steps are you referring to? If you have a working example please share it here.

Comment: Depends on the exact version of Bootstrap you're looking for + the version of Vue you're using but this looks like a detailed guide regarding the whole setup + needed versions: https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs

Comment: If you really want BS5, give a read to that [github issue](https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/issues/5507). Maybe ways to make it work. If it's half-feasible, you will need to deep dive into the exact compatible versions or wait until the v5 is fully ready and migrated. Or cut some corners and hack it yourself. Still, I recommend the usage of Bootstrap-vue if you're using Bootstrap + Vue. I understand that it can be a bit frustrating to deal with that, but this is part of using a CSS UI framework, unfortunately. Also, if the v4 is perfect for you, enjoy!